# PHP - When posting updates, the timezone posted is not what i expect it to be

Tags: php

I have a very simple update page where i post updates with title, content and a timezone. However, i've noticed that since a couple of days the timezone is different from mine.

If my local time is 12.00, it says that it was posted at 10.00. Now i'm not sure why this is happening all of the sudden, so i hope you guys can help me out.

DB structure:
Table: Updates - 
Columns: medewerker, titel, tekst, datum(timestamp)

Here is my code:

```
function PostUpdate() {
try {
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if(!empty($_POST['titel']) && $_POST['tekst']) {
      $mede    = ucfirst($_SESSION['username']);

      $titel = trim($_POST['titel']);
      $titel = strip_tags($titel);
      $titel = htmlspecialchars($titel);

      $tekst = trim($_POST['tekst']);
      $tekst = strip_tags($tekst);
      $tekst = htmlspecialchars($tekst);

      $datum = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

      require('connection.php');

      $insertstmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO updates (medewerker, titel, tekst, datum) VALUES (:medewerker, :titel, :tekst, :datum)');
      $insertstmt->execute(array(':medewerker' => $mede, ':titel' => $titel, ':tekst' => $tekst, ':datum' => $datum));
      header('Refresh:0');
      exit();
    } else {
      echo "Titel of tekst is niet ingevuld.";
    }
  }
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Something went wrong: " . $e->getMessage() . "";
}
```

}

Comment: Is your local timezone UTC+2 by any chance?

Comment: @JonStirling Yes, thats correct.

Comment: Then you're storing it correctly as UTC (imo). You can apply a timezone to it when you want to output it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be happen based on your server(host) (**In local also same**). I faced this issue early with when using `Symfony` on AWS server. To fix I used

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York"); # can change whatever you want
```

Here is the [List of supported time formats](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

---

**In local**(`php.ini`)

```
date.timezone="";
```

Read : [Runtime Configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php)